# bot.get_me() doesn't work and raises an error

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I can manually interact with the bot through url. For example when I send a request to api.telegram.com/bot-token/getMe
the bot's basic info is returned I even get correct results using requests library in python shell but when I try bot.get_me() in the python shell it doesn't work and says this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 140, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, in create_conn
ection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_conn
ection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 614, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 360, in _make_reque
st
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 857, in _validate_c
onn
    super(HTTPSConnectionPool, self)._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 289, in _validate_c
onn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\YM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\
telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3\urllib3\connection.py", line 144, in _new_conn
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(
telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<telegram.v
endor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x024257F
0>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=5.0)')
```

Comment: showing your code may clear it up little

Comment: maybe you need a higher timeout? show your code please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having problems with your internet connection, i.e. the request could not be finished within the timeout of 5 seconds. Keep in mind that a lot of problems can happen unexpectedly in networking. In fact python-telegram-bot has a [wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors) dedicated to that topic. Ofc you could first try to simply increase the timeout, e.g. by passing `timeout=<some_value_>5>` to `get_me`.